# Touch new file with vim's native explorer

Tags: vim

Okay, so I open the explorer with `:Sex` and I am presented with this screen:

[image]

How do I `touch` a new empty file inside `spec/matchers/action_dispatch`? I.e create a file in the directory the explorer is currently inside?

If you're wondering where I got that path from, look at the bottom left of the screen cap.

It would also be cool to do this in the explorer:

```
<d> spec/matcher/action_dispatch/my_folder/my_file.rb
```

Unfortunately, while that creates the desired directory structure, `my_file.rb` is not an empty file but a 5th directory.

How do I touch files in vim's editor?

Comment: ":Sex" this sounds fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the `%` key. See also the help at  `:h netrw-createfile`

Answer (score 0):

This command `:!touch my_directory/my_file` will bring you out Vim, so enter `fg` to go back.

Or you can first navigate to the dirctory you want by `:lcd my_directory` first.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at  :help netrw-browse-maps  .  The answer you seeked (which Christian Brabrandt provided) appears at the end of that listing of maps which netrw provides.